# "to open" and "to close" talking about shop

Tags: words

How to say "at what time does this shop open?" / "at what time does this shop close?".

My dictionary gives no example of this sort with the verbs 開ける, and 開く.

I found 開店する and 閉店する, but it correspond to "open" and "close" in the sense of starting and stopping to run a business.
[Here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-ask-Are-you-open-closed-in-Japanese-talking-about-a-shop) are also some example sentences with these expressions.

There is a discussion [here](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/26546463/What-time-does-this-store-open) and [here](https://hinative.com/questions/10779432) about the "open a shop" here, but not about "to close". They lack examples and explanations.

Reading the documentation from the Internet, I also feel there is a lot of meaning variation depending on the word ひらく (開く), あく (開く), 開ける and the conjugation 開きます, 開いています.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of translation:

**at what time does this shop open?**

Possibilities are:

- この店の開店は{いつ,何時{なんじ}}ですが
- この店は{何時に,いつ}{開{あ}きます,開店します}か
- この店の何時からやってますか (Asking when the shop is already open; sounds more like *Since what time has the shop been open*)

**at what time does this shop close?**

I think it is more usual to ask (literally) **until when is the shop open**.

Possibilities:

- この店は{いつ,何時}まで{やって,開{あ}いて}ますか
- この店の営業時間は何時までですか
- この店の閉店(時間)は何時ですか (This is literally closer to *at what time...close?*)

---

So in terms of vocabulary, 開店/閉店する can be used for *to open/close (a shop) daily*. As you understand, they are also used for *to start/end the business*.

- オープンする may actually be the most frequent for *to start the business*. This can be used for opening the shop daily, but less frequently (I think).
- 開{ひら}く means also more often *to start the business*. For example, 彼女は新宿に店を開{ひら}いた means *She started a shop in Shinjuku*. The subject is the business owner. Cf. 新しいカレー屋が開{ひら}いた sounds less idiomatic to me (カレー屋がオープンした should be more common).

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe I will be a bit annoying, but can you add the kanjis where possible? For instance やって or あいて. Otherwise it can be a bit confusing

Comment: @Starckman Edited. やっている doesn't have kanji.

Comment: やって/やっている  is from やる 'to do', right?

Comment: @Starckman Yes, but *to be (in the state of being) open* is always やっている (progressive of やる). 店をやる can mean *to start a shop/business*.